# How to run a specific version of a ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, brakeman

I am running brakeman outside of my Gemfile, so am not using bundler.

If I do `gem list`, I can see I have the following for brakeman

```
brakeman (3.3.3, 3.3.2, 3.1.4, 3.1.2)
```

But if I do `brakeman --version`, I get

```
brakeman 3.1.2
```

so I am not using the latest version.  If I do `gem update brakeman` or

```
gem update brakeman, '3.3.3,
```

I get

```
Updating installed gems
Nothing to update
```

So how do I run brakeman  version 3.3.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't reproduce this issue, but I can think of a few reasons why this might happen:

- Bundler artifacts (perhaps in `.bundle/`) pointing to the old version. Try running in a different directory and see if it still happens
- A bug in RubyGems (try `gem update --system`)
- During install, it asked if you wanted to replace the `brakeman` binary and you selected "no"
- If you are using a Ruby version manager, maybe one version is on a different path than another (like a system gem versus one managed by `rvm`)
- Any number of `GEM_PATH`, `bundler`, `gem`, `rvm` weirdness that sometimes occurs

In any case, if I were you I'd `gem uninstall brakeman`, remove all versions, and install fresh. If you are using `rvm`, start with a fresh gemset or `rvm gemset empty` the current one.

Comment: It is the nuclear option, but it should work. I am using rvm.  I will try it.

Answer (score 35):

If you have several gem versions installed and you want to invoke a specific version from the command-line, you could use:

```
brakeman _3.3.3_ [args go here]
```

This is not specific to brakeman, you can do this for most other gems as well.

Comment: If I do ```brakeman _3.3.3_ --version``` it still returns 3.1.2, so am I really running 3.3.3?

Comment: I have tried this on another system, and it does work.  There must be something strange with my brakeman installation. I have upvoted your answer.

Comment: To clarify, you can do this for **all** other gems. Try `gem which brakeman` to see that the file you're executing from the command line is really just a shim (script) generated by RubyGems; that shim takes the `_3.3.3_` argument and uses it to determine which version of brakeman to call.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: I uninstalled a certain gem version, but the version still showed up.

TL;DR: `rbenv rehash` did the trick. (Only valid for `rbenv` users, obviously)